# In Visual Studio, find and commands by name?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2013

I'd like to use the keyboard more in Visual Studio, and my memory for `ctrl+alt+f??, alt+??` key combinations is failing me.

I'd prefer an adjunct like the emacs model, where it's possible to search commands by name; For instance, in emacs you type

```
alt+x enab <tab><tab>
```

and it presents you with a list of commands starting 'enab';

```
enable-command
enable-flow-control
enable-theme
```

I'd like to know if there is a shortcut or extension so that I could do something similar in VS, like

```
alt+x imm <tab><tab>
```

and then choose to execute one of

```
Debug.Immediate
Tools.ImmediateMode
```

Any clues?

*EDIT*

Both @Trillian and @the_mandrill have given me the right answers. It turns out there are two ways to enter the kind of mode I'm looking for;

1) The `Edit.GoToFindCombo`, which gives you a small bit of menu-bar space to type things like

```
>Debug.Immediate
```

2) The `View.CommandWindow`, which gives you a full panel (like the immediate window or the output window) which allows you to type in a bit more space and see the text output of executed commands.

It's also possible to alias commands in either window yourself, using the command window and a syntax like

```
alias sol View.SolutionExplorer
```

And to retrieve the current list like

```
alias
```

I've mapped `Edit.GoToFindCombo` to `alt-x` and `View.CommandWindow` to `alt-shift-x` and it's feelimg more emacs-y already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice if this was integrated in the Ctrl+Q Quick Launch box. Until then, the best built-in tool for this is probably the [Go To Find Combo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1665hyw1.aspx). You can use this to launch arbitrary commands by typing the '>' character and then the beginning of a Visual Studio command, including those you listed. You get autocompletion, but only for strings that start with what you're typing, so `>Deb` would list you all commands starting with `Debug.`. For your specific example, `>imm` would actually work because there is an `immed` shortcut to `Debug.Immediate`, but in general you'll have to know the prefix.

The Go To Find Combo is not in the VS2013 UI by default, but you can add it to any toolbar by selecting "Customize" and finding the command in the "Edit" category. Once it's sitting in a toolbar, the Ctrl+/ shortcut will give it the focus by default.

The '>' prefix for command completion also works from the Command and Immediate windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Command Window (Ctrl-Alt-A).  This brings up an emacs-like command buffer. Type:

```
Deb.Imm<tab>
```

to expand to `Debug.Immediate`. Typing the '.' forces autocompletion if there's one unique command (Debug is the only match for 'De'). Tab key will cycle through options.  More info at the [Command Window article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c785s0kz.aspx) on MSDN. There's also a list of [Aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3a0kd3x.aspx) that you can also add your own to, eg

```
alias di Debug.Immediate
```

I've also just discovered that you can type `Ctrl-\` to set the focus to the Find pane and enter a command directly in there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment -- both you and @Trillian gave me the right answers, but Trillian is more in need of the right points. Really helpful -- thank again.